# How to transform roadline uid to point geometry?

Tags: qgis

I have a road line geom and roadline uid attribute. How to transform selected roadline uid to selected points geoms?

ArcGIS has spatial adjustment tool, does QGIS have a similar tool?

[image]

A spatial join doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in QGIS is the [Vector Bender](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/) plugin.

Look at this video for some examples of things it can do
https://vimeo.com/96142479